# Watch unused Local Variable is impossible? Why?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, architecture

I wrote a console test program, it should call a method and returns value.
but i didn't use of final variable. when i test it i couldn't Add variable to watch section. 
this error appears in watch window

```
The name 'myvariable' does not exist in the current context
```

My code:

```
  var myvariable =  SyncService.ModelToXml(tables);
```

modelToXml is a simple method. but when i changed to this i could watch myvariable.

```
 var myvariable =  SyncService.ModelToXml(tables);
 var anothervariable = myvariable;
```

so i tried this code:

```
 var xxxx = 1000;
```

i couldn't watch xxxx too.
i've this question that when we don't use of variables, .net will remove them in compile mode? yes or not?? if not what's the reason that i can't watch it...

Comment: Is there an easier code syntax to reproduce this without the ModelToXML method? As in, is it a lazy loaded object? or deferred execution? async?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the compiler removes unused variables if the `optimize` option is set. You can edit this setting under the projects settings.

Open the project's Properties page.

Click the Build property page.

Modify the Optimize Code property.